# p-table' is not a known element - Custom module

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to add a table to my component trying to make it ork for the first time
this is the error

---

Error: src/app/demo/components/apps/anas-c/anas-c.component.html:41:1 - error NG8001: 'p-table' is not a known element:

1. If 'p-table' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

41 <p-table

````
42   >
~~~

src/app/demo/components/apps/anas-c/anas-c.component.ts:22:16
 22   templateUrl: './anas-c.component.html'
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 Error occurs in the template of component AnasCComponent.

----

this is my component:

```

<h2 style="color: green">GeeksforGeeks</h2> 
<h4>Angular PrimeNG Table Sort</h4> 
<!--
 [value]="tableData" 
 scrollHeight="400px"
-->
<p-table 
     > 
 <ng-template pTemplate="header"> 
     <tr> 
         <th pSortableColumn="firstname">First Name</th> 
         <th pSortableColumn="age">Age</th> 
     </tr> 
 </ng-template> 

 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-people> 
     <tr> 
         <td> 
             {{ people.firstname }} 
         </td> 
         <td> 
             {{ people.age }} 
         </td> 
     </tr> 
 </ng-template> 
</p-table>
```

this is my component.ts:


```


import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer, Representative } from 'src/app/demo/api/customer';
import { Product } from 'src/app/demo/api/product';


import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table'; 

interface People { 
firstname?: string; 
lastname?: string; 
age?: string; 
} 

interface expandedRows {
[key: string]: boolean;
}

let value;
@Component({
selector: 'app-anas-c',
templateUrl: './anas-c.component.html'
})
export class AnasCComponent {

customers1: Customer[] = [];

customers2: Customer[] = [];

customers3: Customer[] = [];

selectedCustomers1: Customer[] = [];

selectedCustomer: Customer = {};

representatives: Representative[] = [];

statuses: any[] = [];

products: Product[] = [];

rowGroupMetadata: any;

expandedRows: expandedRows = {};

activityValues: number[] = [0, 100];

isExpanded: boolean = false;

idFrozen: boolean = false;

loading: boolean = true;

tableData: People[] = []; 
cols: any[] = []; 


metrics: any[] = [];


constructor() {
 let metrics = {
   title: 'Total Revenue',
   value: 0,
   currency: '$',
   change: 0,
   trend: 'up',
   trendValue: 0,
   trendPercent: 0
 };
 let content = {
   amount: 0,
   change: 0,
   text  : "anas"
 };
}

ngOnInit(): void {

};

}

```
this is my routing.module.ts 

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AnasCComponent } from './anas-c.component';

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
     { path: '', component: AnasCComponent }
 ])],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AnasCComponentRoutingModule { }

```

this is my module.ts 

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext';
import { ToggleButtonModule } from 'primeng/togglebutton';
import { RippleModule } from 'primeng/ripple';
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/multiselect';
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/dropdown';
import { ProgressBarModule } from 'primeng/progressbar';
import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast';
import { SliderModule } from 'primeng/slider';
import { RatingModule } from 'primeng/rating';
import { AnasCComponent } from './anas-c.component';

import { AnasCComponentRoutingModule } from './anas-routing.module';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
     CommonModule,
     AnasCComponentRoutingModule,
     FormsModule,
     TableModule,
     RatingModule,
     ButtonModule,
     SliderModule,
     InputTextModule,
     ToggleButtonModule,
     RippleModule,
     MultiSelectModule,
     DropdownModule,
     ProgressBarModule,
     ToastModule
 ],
 declarations: [AnasCComponent]
})
export class AnasCComponentoModule { }
```
any idea


i tried reinstalling the library and change the declaration nd imports and stuff
````

Comment: could you replicate the issue in a stackblitz and share back, if its a public github repo please share the link!

Comment: @NarenMurali these are the component files  https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ebqhyh?file=tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something else wrong with your code. As far as I can see there are the changes I made!

1. You need to specify the attribute `[value]="tableData"` for the table to render

I suspect that one of the modules is erroring out, mostly a shared module, this is giving the side effect of this error, so validate your code for the other errors!

```
<p-table [value]="tableData">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th pSortableColumn="firstname">First Name</th>
      <th pSortableColumn="age">Age</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-people>
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{ people.firstname }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ people.age }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bqt141?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fanas%2Fanas.module.ts,src%2Fanas%2Fanas-c.component.ts,src%2Fanas%2Fanas-c.component.html,src%2Fanas%2Fanas-routing.module.ts)

Comment: apparently if i create the component with the angular CLI for some reasons primeng doesn't work

Comment: @nasgr if its a public repository share the link, I will debug it!

Comment: @nasgr ok fine!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if i create the component with the angular CLI for some reasons primeng doesn't work.
You need to create the component manually.
Thanks everyone